# Finding the distance from the center of airy disc to first airy minimum?

Tags: visible-light

This image is taken from the manual of photography, by Elizabeth Allen:

[image]

How do I find it? The formula is supposed to tell me how to find this distance, but the formula requires R which depends on me already knowing this distance? Did I misunderstand massively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this. The first is to note that $R$ is related to $\gamma_1$ and the distance to the centre of the ring, $L$:

[image: Ray diagram]

From Pythagoras' theorem we know:

$$ R^2 = L^2 + \gamma_1^2 $$

And we can substitute this into the formula for $\gamma_1$ to get:

$$ \gamma_1 = 1.22 \frac{\lambda}{d} \sqrt{ L^2 + \gamma_1^2 } $$

and with a bit of rearranging we get:

$$ \gamma_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1.4884\lambda^2}{d^2 - 1.4884\lambda^2}} L \tag{1} $$

The second approach is simply to note that in most cases $\lambda_1$ is much less than $R$, and therefore that $R \approx L$. In that case the equation for $\gamma_1$ approximates to:

$$ \gamma_1 \approx 1.22 \frac{L\lambda}{d} \tag{2} $$

To make this concrete let's apply it to the size of the Airy disk created by the pupil of your eye when watching TV. We'll take the diameter of the pupil in your eye to be 4 mm, the distanceto the TV to be 3 m and the wavelength of the light to be 600 nm. Then equation (1) gives:

$$ \gamma_1 = 0.00054900008 \,\text{m} $$

and equation (2) gives:

$$ \gamma_1 = 0.000549 \,\text{m} $$

So the simpler equation (2) is an excellent approximation.